# how to have same package-lock.json for all node / npm versions

Tags: node.js, npm, package-lock.json

Is it possible to have different node versions (lts and current) and have the same `package-lock.json`?

Currently when I run `npm install` the packages it generates are different to those specified in the `package-lock.json` file.

For example I'm using `nvm` (node version manager) to test different node versions on the same machine.

`nvm exec v10.3.0 npm i` outputs `package-lock.json` :

```json
"babel-generator": {
  "version": "6.26.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-generator/-/babel-generator-6.26.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-HyfwY6ApZj7BYTcJURpM5tznulaBvyio7/0d4zFOeMPUmfxkCjHocCuoLa2SAGzBI8AREcH3eP3758F672DppA==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "babel-messages": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-types": "^6.26.0",
    "detect-indent": "^4.0.0",
    "jsesc": "^1.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "source-map": "^0.5.7",
    "trim-right": "^1.0.1"
  }
},
```

`nvm exec v8.11.2 npm i` outputs `package-lock.json` :

```json
 "babel-generator": {
  "version": "6.26.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-generator/-/babel-generator-6.26.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-HyfwY6ApZj7BYTcJURpM5tznulaBvyio7/0d4zFOeMPUmfxkCjHocCuoLa2SAGzBI8AREcH3eP3758F672DppA==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "babel-messages": "6.23.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "babel-types": "6.26.0",
    "detect-indent": "4.0.0",
    "jsesc": "1.3.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "source-map": "0.5.7",
    "trim-right": "1.0.1"
  }
},
```

And because of that a lot of git conflicts keep happening between these two version.

Is there any configuration in `package.json` to have same output for `package-lock.json` ?

Comment: you mean to say different node version can create different package.json right?

Comment: different node versions can create different package-lock.json